# Как организовать Spring MVC

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Пишу Веб-приложение на Java. Для входа необходима авторизация. Для этого создал таблицу Пользователи в базе данных. В самой системе (Телефонная книга)  пользователь вносит записи ( имена, телефоны, адреса) - для этого создал вторую таблицу Записи.

Как лучше всего реализовать чтобы  пользователь видел только свои записи, только  которые  он сам создал?

Comment: В таблицу телефонных записей добавить внешний ключ на пользователя, создавшего запись. При операциях над данными проверять соответствие автора и текущего пользователя.

Comment: эту логику я сам тогда должен прописать буду в контроллере? Может можно както менее трудоёмко через сессии к примеру?

Comment: Да там писать-то две-три строки.

Comment: спасибо. я Вас понял.